# window.location redirect not working in Android

Tags: javascript, android

I'm trying to redirect to a different page using javascript. It works nicely with Firefox but not with Android. Here's a sample code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="content-type" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.write("1: " + window.location.href + "<br />");
    window.location = "http://www.google.com";
    document.write("2: " + window.location.href + "<br />");
    window.location.href = "http://www.google.com";
    document.write("3: " + window.location.href + "<br />");
    window.location.assign("http://www.google.com");
    document.write("4: " + window.location.href + "<br />");                       
</script>
<title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

The goal is to redirect to google.com and I'm trying 3 different approaches. Firefox redirects immediately. Android prints the first location and then stops. If I comment out

```
window.location = "http://www.google.com";
```

then it prints the first two and stops. And so on. For some reason, I can read window.location just fine but when I try to modify it, the script hangs. Any help would be great. Using Android 2.2.

Comment: Have you tried it with "console.log()" instead of "document.write()"?  Just a random thought.

Comment: [Here is a test page that works fine for me from my Android phone.](http://gutfullofbeer.net/redir.html)

Comment: @Pointy Thank you! I guess that means there is something wrong in my environment and not the code. To be honest I'm testing it through an Android emulator (due to the lack of an actual phone) and your page is just blank when I use Android 2.3 but works as expected with 2.1. Can you let me know what version you are using? If it's an emulator problem then that's fine. But if the Android release is the culprit then that's a problem.

Comment: I *think* my phone is 2.2 (it's a fairly new Moto "Atrix") - let me see if I can figure out how to make sure :-) *edit* yup it's Android 2.2.1

Answer (score 1):

Try `window.location.href`:

```
window.location.href = "http://www.google.com";
```

Comment: Thanks, but I tried it and it's included in the code as well (location, location.href and location.assign()).
Can you verify that it works for you? Is there something else that I'm missing?

Comment: Try it first... you overwrite the `location` object as a simple string so it loses it's `href` property.

Comment: it works without .href just fine; the "location" object is not a native JavaScript object, and assigning to "location" does not do as you suggest.

Comment: @Pointy thanks for the clarification.  I expected it to work like other js objects.